# Способы вызова функции класса в php

Tags: php, классы

Я заметил два способа вызова функции какого либо класса, есть кто может разъяснить их отличия?
Вот пример:
`core::getInfo()` или же `$core->getInfo()`

Comment: @Фарход - очень сильно советую должным образом изучить ООП (причем лучше, если есть возможность, не на примере PHP, а, например, на примере java, c++ etc.), мало того, что вы не будете задавать таких глупых вопросов, так вы еще и понимать что-то будете :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На самом деле, это два абсолютно разных вызова! Первый вызов - это вызов функции не из объекта класса, сконструированного после определения класса, а непосредственно из самого класса. НО! Так можно вызывать только статические методы, то есть методы, принадлежащие самому классу. Такие методы определяются спецификатором **"static"**:

```
class A{
...
static function print($msg){echo $msg;}
...
}
A::print('Hello World!');   // статический вызов
```

Ну, а второй вызов, это уже стандартный вызов метода класса из его объекта:

```
class A{
...
function print($msg){echo $msg;}
...
}
A $a;
$a->print('Hello World!');  // вызов из объекта класса
...
```

Comment: В чем плюс или минус вызова не посредственно из класса, а не из обекта класса?

Comment: Думаю, что не стоит так разбрасываться словом "интерфейс". Кроме того, вы описали **инкапсуляцию**, а **не** полиморфизм. Так что за пониманием ООП вам тоже следует обратиться.

Полиморфизм позволяет в процессе наследования, например, изменить тот единственный метод для **обслуживания данных**, назовем это так.

Comment: @Фарход, на ваш вопрос на форуме уже отвечали. Смысл пользования статическими функциями имеет место, например, когда она (функция) логически принадлежит определенному классу, но фактически не имеет взаимодействия с полями класса. (например, для случая, когда параметров функции и возвращаемого значения (если есть) достаточно, чтобы произвести некоторую обработку).

Comment: @Asen, да будет так:)

Answer (score 1):

Вот определение которое поможет понять разницу между статическими методами и свойствами классов и методами,св-вами объектов.

> Статические методы - это функции, используемые в контексте класса. Они сами не могут получить доступ ни к каким обычным свойствам класса, потому что такие свойства принадлежат объектам. Однако из статических методов можно обращаться к статическим свойствам. И если вы измените статическое свойство, то все экземпляры этого класса смогут получить доступ к новому значению.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте цитату в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения.

Answer (score 1):

В PHP, как ни странно, не является синтаксической ошибкой вызов не статического метода статическим способом. Но генерирует предупреждения. Но вызывать оператором :: обычные методы категорически не рекомендуется - это сулит радикальное снижение читаемости кода, и суровые баги.