# self и this

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, уважаемые хэшкодеры!

```
class Example
{
 function __construct(){...};
 function One(){...};
 function Two(){ Нужно вызвать первую функцию! };
}
```

Вопрос - что лучше использовать: $this->One(); или self::One(); ?
Работает и то и то, чем отличаются знаю, хотелось бы узнать как правильней
с точки зрения парадигмы ООП, скорости выполнения, феншуя и УГ РФ.

Comment: По поводу оператора **::**, можно пробежаться по статье [Обращение к элементам классов в PHP5 (::)](http://www.php.su/learnphp/phpoo/?php5_pm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Способы вызова функции класса в php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/104346/class-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-php)